# bad using of if instruction

Tags: java, loops

I have some situations using if sentence, It add aditional value to my request.. I'm doing a paper,stone,scissors game, there are another form instead if sentence?:

```
if ("stone".equals(movePlayer1) && "stone".equals(moveComputer)) {
        draw = draw + 1;

    }
    if ("paper".equals(movePlayer1) && "paper".equals(moveComputer)) {
        draw = draw + 1;
    }
    if ("Scissors".equals(movePlayer1) && "Scissors".equals(moveComputer)) {
        draw = draw + 1;
    }
    if ("paper".equals(movePlayer1) && "Scissors".equals(moveComputer)) {
        win = win + 1;

    }

    if ("paper".equals(movePlayer1) && "stone".equals(moveComputer)) {
        win = win + 1;

    }

    if ("Scissors".equals(movePlayer1) && "paper".equals(moveComputer)) {
        win = win + 1;

    }

    if ("stone".equals(movePlayer1) && "stone".equals(moveComputer)) {
        serverwin = serverwin + 1;

    }

    if ("paper".equals(movePlayer1) && "Scissors".equals(moveComputer)) {
        serverwin = serverwin + 1;

    }

    if ("Scissors".equals(movePlayer1) && "stone".equals(moveComputer)) {
        serverwin = serverwin + 1;

    }
```

There is another way to do that like switch, else or something like that?

Comment: What is your error? Please don't make us work harder than we need to.

Comment: Quick java tip: Instead of doing x = x + 1, you should do x += 1.

Comment: one more tip: Instead of Strings, use String Constants or ENUMS

Also "stone".equals(movePlayer1) && "stone".equals(moveComputer) is repeated?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In an implementation of Rock, Paper, Scissors, both the player and computer make a choice simultaneously, and then those choices are compared. Either the player wins, the computer wins, or the players draw. As soon as you have detected one of those conditions, it's no longer necessary to make further evaluation.

When you code many `if` statements as you have, each statement is independent of the others. Even if the first `if` statement evaluates to `true`, all the remaining `if` statements will still be evaluated.

Rather than using many `if` statements, you should be using `if... else if... else` which effectively ties many conditions together in a mutually exclusive fashion and will pass control back out of the code block as soon as one of those statements has evaluated to `true`.

```
if ("stone".equals(movePlayer1) && "stone".equals(moveComputer))
{
    draw = draw + 1;
}
else if ("paper".equals(movePlayer1) && "paper".equals(moveComputer))
{
    draw = draw + 1;
}
else if ("Scissors".equals(movePlayer1) && "Scissors".equals(moveComputer))
{
    draw = draw + 1;
}

// continue your code below
```

Please make sure you understand the [fundamentals of flow control](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) before proceeding further.

Answer (score 0):

How about following approach?

```
    switch (movePlayer1) {
    case "stone":
        switch (moveComputer) {
        case "stone":
            draw++;
            break;
            // check rest of stone vs moveComputer value here
        }
        break;

    case "paper":
        switch (moveComputer) {
        case "paper":
            draw++;
            break;
            // check rest of paper vs moveComputer value here
        }
        break;

    case "Scissors":
        switch (moveComputer) {
        case "Scissors":
            draw++;
            break;
            // check rest of Scissors vs moveComputer value here
        }
        break;
    }
```